# x86 assembly OS hello world not working as expected

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

i made this code, this should be simple OS, that should print "Hello world!".

```
bits 16
  mov bx,msg
  call printstr
printstr:
  mov al,byte[bx]
  mov ah,0Eh
  int 10h
  inc bx
  cmp byte[bx],0
  je end
  jmp printstr
end:
  jmp end
msg: db "Hello world!",0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I assembled that on NASM.
When i run it on QEMU, it prints one strange character, and 'S'.

I ran QEMU with those arguments
"qemu-system-x86_64 ost.bin" where "ost.bin" is that file.
Does anybody know solution?

Comment: You might want to track this SO question as well. They seem quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515203/first-os-i-cant-make-it-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

```
bits 16
 mov bx, msg
```

`msg` now contains only offset of your message from start of output binary. You can solve this problem by either adding `0x7c00` to `msg` or setting program origin (start in memory, `ORG 0x7c00`).

```
  call printstr
printstr:
  mov al,byte[bx]
```

`BX` is not good register for indexing strung characters, as it contains color (lower byte) and page (higher byte) information.

```
  mov ah,0Eh
  int 10h
```

You don't have to set `AH` to `0x0E` everytime you print a character. It can be done on the start of code.

```
  inc bx
  cmp byte[bx], 0
```

In this kind of loops, you should first check value, and then process it. What would you do if character on `BX+0` was equal to `0`? You would miss that fact and that would cause wrong output or even endless loop.

```
  je end
  jmp printstr
```

This will surely cause endless loop, as you already are in that procedure.

```
end:
  jmp end
```

Prefered syntax is `jmp $` (where dollar sign means "here").

```
msg: db "Hello world!",0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert "**org 7c00h**" at the beginning of the code.

And also, you have to stop the program after printing, or else it will fall into printstr procedure once again.

Maybe something like:

```
sleep: hlt 
       jmp sleep
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that the segment registers (DS and ES) are not initialized.

The "org 7C00h" is not required; the program may also start at address 100h (ideal for DOS .COM files) or 0h. Depending on the start address the segment registers must be initialized to 7C0h (org 0h), 7B0H (org 100h) or 0 (org 7C00h).

The "jmp sleep" instruction at the end is sufficient; a "HLT" instruction is definitely not needed.

Comment: Worked fine with org 7c00h.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau It would be an interesting DOS program, being exactly 512 bytes wide and having bootloader signature on the end.

Comment: Martin is right! QEMU may initialize your segment registers to 0, but you can't count on it in a bootsector!

Comment: A real HW BIOS will initialize the segment registers as well.